# Why Active Storage Embeds Text Message on the Page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I activated active storage in my project and uploaded my pictures. When I show the pictures on the page, the following message appears below the last picture:

`<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 28, name: "images", record_type: "Category", record_id: 14, blob_id: 28, created_at: "2020-01-23 06:49:00">, #<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 29, name: "images", record_type: "Category", record_id: 14, blob_id: 29, created_at: "2020-01-23 06:49:00">, #<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 30, name: "images", record_type: "Category", record_id: 14, blob_id: 30, created_at: "2020-01-23 06:49:00">, #<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 31, name: "images", record_type: "Category", record_id: 14, blob_id: 31, created_at: "2020-01-23 06:49:00">, #<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 32, name: "images", record_type: "Category", record_id: 14, blob_id: 32, created_at: "2020-01-23 06:49:00">, #<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 33, name: "images", record_type: "Category", record_id: 14, blob_id: 33, created_at: "2020-01-23 06:49:00">, #<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 34, name: "images", record_type: "Category", record_id: 14, blob_id: 34, created_at: "2020-01-23 06:49:00">]`

**How do remove this message?**

Here are some of my codes:

**Controller:**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def photos
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**View:**

```
  <% if @category.images.attached? %>
    <%= @category.images.each do |image| %>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" data-aos="fade-up">
        <%= link_to(image, class:'d-block photo-item', 'data-fancybox' => 'gallery') do %>

          <%= image_tag(image, alt:'image', class:'img-fluid') %>

          <div class="photo-text-more">
            <span class="icon icon-search"></span>
          </div>

        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**Solution:**

```
<%= @category.images.each do |image| %>
```

It fix when I removed the "=" expression here.

Comment: FYI: `<%= ... %>` prints the result, whereas `<% ... %>` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your script `<%= @category.images.each do |image| %>` where you included `=` which is the reason for getting the above output.

In Rails ERB file if you type `=`, it will print the output the result of that operation.

So, remove the `=` and you will get the expected result. Updated code.

```
<% if @category.images.attached? %>
    <% @category.images.each do |image| %>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" data-aos="fade-up">
        <%= link_to(image, class:'d-block photo-item', 'data-fancybox' => 'gallery') do %>

          <%= image_tag(image, alt:'image', class:'img-fluid') %>

          <div class="photo-text-more">
            <span class="icon icon-search"></span>
          </div>

        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```